# why aren't PHP extensions built in?

Tags: php-extension

why aren't PHP extensions built in?

Also, where can I look in phpinfo to determine if my ISP has installed the PHP extensions?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: because they're extensions.  Anyone can make an extension independent of the core developer group's work on the php runtime and their release schedule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP extensions aren't built in because for the most part the PHP team isn't responsible for them. They can be developed by third-party developers.

Also there is a big number of available PHP extensions. Having **all** of them built into PHP would result in a very large PHP distribution and would increase memory requirements.
Some of them are specific to certain database engines (eg. postgre, oracle, mysql), while hosting services may only provide one engine like mysql. It wouldn't make sense to include useless extensions.

For the second question, PHP has a function to programmatically check for the presence of a given extension:

[extension_loaded()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extension-loaded.php)

From the documentation:

> bool extension_loaded ( string $name )
>
> Finds out whether the extension is loaded.

Finding out in phpinfo output whether specific extensions are installed is just a matter of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> for the text.

Comment: SirDarius, thank you very much for the in-depth answer. This helps tremendously. Can you tell me SirDarius if it's just a matter of uploading an extension to the PHP files (since they are just classes; usually), or would it depend on the ISP service offerings???

Comment: I'm searching Stackoverflow in case my questions regarding loading ext. has been answered. I want you to know that I'm making an effort to learn. So, I will post back should I find the answer before you get back. I would like to say thank you again!!

Comment: Extensions are libraries (.so files on Unix, .dll files on windows) that must be explicitely loaded through PHP ini files, so yes, it can only be done by someone that has write access to these files, in your case, the ISP.